# Nav that fills up width of page in responsive design

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

I have designed a responsive layout that you can see here: http://pixelcakecreative.com/cimlife/responsive/

When viewed on a display that is less that 1550px wide, there is a small problem. I want that nav bar to fill up the entire width of the `<nav>` element.

My HTML is set up like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contests</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

In my css, I have given each `<a>` some padding. The padding is the variable that should change based on the page width, so using px will not work. I cant use percentages because each `<li>` has a different width (different amount of text). Is there a good solution (jquery or css) to spread out the navbar across the entire width of the `<nav>`?

The attached picture is the desired effect[image]

Comment: Noticed that the width of your first li element is 898px. If i set its width to auto it goes down to 543px but visually nothing changes. I was thinking that width:auto would have fixed it.

Comment: You shouldn't constrain the height of your navigation. Please use min-height instead, that'll allow - only when needed - your content to be displayed in cases you didn't think of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

nav ul li {
    float:none;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

This solution will let the browser lay stuff out as it sees fit - wider `li`s will be given more width that narrower ones.

Answer (score 2):

For the container of the menu items makes its `width:100%` and as you have 5 menu elements make them have a `width:20%`

Hope this helps

**Update**

Try this also

```
#menu      { width:100%; }
#menu li   { width:20%;  pading:10px 0;  text-align:center; }
```

Try not to put padding on the left and right of elements when designing responsive and fluid websites, as it can break the layout.

**Update Update**

On a sidenote, something thing you may have noticed is when you scale your site down to say 240px (which alot of mobile devices use) it is very small.

You may want to look into CSS3 Media Queries over at css-tricks http://css-tricks.com/6731-css-media-queries/

They are a way to apply different styles to a page at certain points, like document width > 240px && < 480px

Comment: this has media queries, just resize!!! Thanks for the solution, this iwll work although I did not want each li to have the same width.